# Rails 4.0.0 install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I am trying to set up a ruby on rails environment. But I don't understand the error I am seeing when trying to install rails 4.0.0 (below). How do I fix this?

> ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-208:~/rails_project$ sudo gem install rails --version 4.0.0

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

> ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-208:~/rails_project$ ruby -v

```
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: How'd you install ruby?

Comment: `sudo` might use the system ruby, which would likely be 1.8.7. What is the output of `sudo ruby -v`?

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-208:~$ sudo ruby -v

       ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
ubuntu@ip-172-31-43-208:~$ ruby -v

       ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: The comment is not properly formatted but the output is ruby1.9.3p0. BTW why is the output of ruby -v different from sudo ruby -v? I am fairly familiar with Linux and I am surprised..